# stackoverflowerror when try to access web application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I was trying to create simple web application.
Here is my `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>basicServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pack.BasicServlet </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>basicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my `index.jsp` that located in `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Basic web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Data provided by server:</h2>
        <p>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${ not empty message }">
                    <h3>${message}</h3>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <h3>none</h3>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `servlet`

```
public class BasicServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private IBasicService basicService;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        basicService = new BasicService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("message", basicService.provideMessage());
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp").forward(req, resp); // 23 line
    }
}
```

I built a `war` and deployed it in tomcat. But when I try to access it I get long stack trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
...
```

with `root cause`

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
com.pack.BasicServlet.doGet(BasicServlet.java:22)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
....
```

What is the problem? I used `servlets` long time ago so maybe I forgot about something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have bound your servlet to URL pattern `/*`, so every request on its context will be directed to the servlet.  The servlet's `doGet()` method attempts to forward requests to URL `/jsp/index.jsp`, but, like every other URL in the servlet's context, that will be directed (back) to the servlet.  This creates an infinite recursion, which is in fact evident in your stack trace.

Bind your servlet instead to a more specific URL pattern.  Alternatively, if you want to pre-process every inbound request, then consider implementing that via a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) instead of a servlet.