# stackoverflowerror when try to run web application

Tags: servlets, stack-overflow

this is my servlet for user profile in web app. i made it /users/* pattern so every user would have it's own url.

```
@WebServlet(name = "Account",urlPatterns = "/users/*")
public class PersonalAccountServlet extends HttpServlet {
private final UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") == null){
        resp.sendRedirect("/main");
    } else {
        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
        UserDto userDTO = userService.getByName(userName);
        req.setAttribute("user", userDTO);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("profile.ftl").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
}
```

nothing strange. but running this code gives me 500 error - stackoverflow.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
proj.servlets.PersonalAccountServlet.doGet(PersonalAccountServlet.java:28)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
proj.servlets.PersonalAccountServlet.doGet(PersonalAccountServlet.java:28)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
proj.servlets.PersonalAccountServlet.doGet(PersonalAccountServlet.java:28)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
```

How does it happen?

Comment: I found similar problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505168/stackoverflowerror-when-try-to-access-web-application
But solution there doesn't help my situation as mine doesn't have obvious recursion like that

Comment: Does the filter applies to `*/ ` as you posted or to `/*`?

Comment: @LMC /*, my bad

Comment: Comment the redirect out and see what error you get

Comment: i think i gripped something: when i do 'req.getRequestDispatcher("profile.ftl").forward(req, resp);', i execute .../users/profile.ftl implicitly so it matches my url pattern and goes into else block again and again. maybe.

Comment: but it seems i can't avoid this recursion at all... like i have to redirect any users/* pattern into this servlet but users/profile.ftl doesn't have to

Comment: so the filter pattern isn't `/*` but something more elaborated or with exclusions.

Comment: fixed the problem. i just replaced profile.ftl with /profile.ftl and it worked(???). i guess if path has no / inside it's considered as relative and is being executed in servlet's context(users/). but if i add / it's considered as absolute and code is being executed right after application context(global one)

Comment: [*The pathname must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the current context root.*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String))